# View the file associated with a tag that doesn't appear in the current file

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Often times I'm editing a file and I want to look at the definition of `class FooBar` but I don't know what file `FooBar` is defined in. I do know, however, that `FooBar` is in my `tags` file. I could just type out `FooBar` and then position my cursor on it and hit `ctrl+]`, but that feels too messy.

How can I jump to the `FooBar` tag when `FooBar` doesn't appear in the current file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
:tag FooBar
```

ProTip: use `<tab>` or `<c-d>` completion with `:tag` arguments.

See `:h :tag`